# Get zoom size on Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I get the zoom size in google map after changing by mouse wheel or zoom bar ?

I use Google Map API 3 with JavaScript.

I want to show in `console.log()` with every change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easy. [As per docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var z = map.getZoom();
    console.log(z);
});
```

Here's [a great utility](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html) that shows all the events as they fire.

Answer (score 3):

`map.getZoom()`.

It's in [`the docs!`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

Comment: Thanks, but this method just return zoom in first time, and after changing with mouse wheel this method cannot return zoom value :-(

Comment: @MajAfy Ah, so you want to listen for when the user changes the zoom? Check out the `zoom_changed` event, as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can use zoom_changed event for this..

[check this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-properties)

Comment: @MajAfy, check this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep a div that will show the map I am having ('map_canvas').

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        disableDefaultUI : true,
        zoom : 12,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(17.1312321,78.23123123),
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });



google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed',function() {
console.log(map.getZoom());
});
```